# How to create SQL Function such that it accepts date or null value

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

How to create SQL Function such that it accepts date or null value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function func(dob timestamp)
RETURNS TABLE(greet varchar, age int) AS $$
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN dob IS NULL
            THEN ('no birth'::text, 0)
        WHEN dob >= '2000-01-01'
            THEN ('post millennium', 21)
        ELSE ('does not match', -1)
    END
$$
language sql stable strict;
```

Here I want to accept date value or null. It is not working when I pass null. I am getting empty record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `strict` attribute.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#id-1.9.3.67.6)

> RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT or STRICT indicates that the function always returns null whenever any of its arguments are null. If this parameter is specified, **the function is not executed when there are null arguments**; instead a null result is assumed automatically.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I thought of type issue. now I know what strict mean...

Comment: @VinitKhandelwal: works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9834d7e0d51425f5013fb8c3e96b2a9c

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name here in this function I am using this but not working
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71613680/sql-custom-function-is-not-returning-data-as-expected-by-matching-to-my-conditio